# C# sql database doesn't save data after calling UpdatePlayer function

Tags: c#, sql, database

So i have this client/server game and the following problem occurs:

Everything is working fine unless server calls sql database to update the player using function called "UpdatePlayer".

Example: You login with character, go in space and you die. Server calls the function DestroyUser where is set what happens when a player dies and then it calls "UpdatePlayer(Victomcheck)", where Victomcheck = died player.

After server calls UpdatePlayer, the database is going messy and wont save any data after that.

Example: You start client, register user and when you logout and login again using your Login and Password, it says incorrect password (data wasn't saved to the sql database).

Debug Output:
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Problem happens in SQLDataBase.cs file at line 121 (it's commented on the code below):

```
        DataSet Results = null;
        int RETURN_VALUE = 0;
        try
        {

            Results = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
            adapter.Fill(Results); //LINE 121
            Connection.Close();
            Connection = null;

            RETURN_VALUE = System.Convert.ToInt32(Command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value);

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return new StoredProcRet(RETURN_VALUE, Results);
    }
```

Here's the updateplayer function:

```
    static public void UpdatePlayer(int check)
    {

        Player p = new Player(DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_User(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserName(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPass(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserEmail(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserLastIP(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserHomePlanet(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserLastPlanet(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserMoney(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserExperience(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserLastShip(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan2(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan3(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan4(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan5(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan6(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan7(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan8(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserPlan9(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShip1(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShip2(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShip3(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShip4(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShip5(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShipMisc1(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShipMisc2(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShipMisc3(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShipMisc4(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserShipMisc5(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserGuild(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserGuildRank(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserGuildLent(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserGenKills(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserVelicKills(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserGenVelicExp(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserUniversalCredits(check), DatabasePlayerAdapter.get_UserDeaths(check));
        sqlPlay.UpdatePlayer(p);
    }
```

I don't understand why this problem happens, please help. I can provide any other required code you want. Thank you very much!

Comment: whats the full exception message of the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` ? what (if any) is the inner exception message? That's what will tell you whats going wrong.

Comment: It only says "Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll". How to i view the full exception message and the inner message ? Sorry, im so new to C# ...

Comment: To get the exception message look at ex.Message.  The inner exception can be found at ex.InnerException with ex.InnerException.Message having the message (be careful, InnerException can be null!)

Comment: Simple question maybe, but are you sure you are commiting your data to the DB?  Although this would not cause the exception

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of researching i found the exact line where the bug occurs. It happens when attack a bot (engage) in the game and then cancel the attack (disengage). The exact line is:

```
DatabasePlayerAdapter.set_UserEngageCheck(check, BotMemory.BotNameToCheck(Victom));
```

So i assume it's something to deal with .set_UserEngageCheck which is located in DatabasePlayerAdapter.cs

```
        public static void set_UserEngageCheck(int i, int value)
    {
        get_Player(i).EngageCheck = value;
    }
```

Any ideas ?